# BufferGeometry - only one side gets material applied?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to `three.js`.
I created a test polygon with the following code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
var vertices = new Float32Array([
    2.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,

    1.0, 1.0, 2.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
]);
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);
```

I expected the polygon to be colored red on every side. However only one side is red, the other is black.

How can I fix this?

I created a fiddle but for some reason it is not working (at least my test file's
full code can be found here):

## [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hp1rswg/12/)

Move the mouse horizontally to rotate the polygon horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this produce the desired result?

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
```

See this link in the documentation for more detail:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material.side